# Visibility of "this" in Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have two cases

```
const test = {
    foo: function (){
        this.bar();
    },
    bar: function (){
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
test.foo();
```

in this case, everything works correctly.

```
const test = {
    foo: () => {
        this.bar();
    },
    bar: () => {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
test.foo();
```

In second case I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined
```

I know I can wrote `test.bar()` in `foo` function, but I'm interested why `this` not available in arrow functions scope in this case.

Comment: scope in fat arrow function doesn't take context of the object it was called on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the value of `this` in a function depends on how that function is called.

Arrow functions import the value of `this` from the scope in which the function was created.

In the middle of an object literal, the value of `this` will depend on what is around the object literal, but certainly won't be the object itself.